# Count paths in a cube

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question about this exercise. I understand that the solution to this type of exercise lies in how many words can be formed with a certain number of letters, but my doubt is about the way in which it can be moved, because the problem says that it can go backwards. I would appreciate your support!

> Inside a wire cube $C$ of dimensions $ 5 \times 5 \times 5$, wires are placed by dividing it into cubes of dimensions $1 \times 1 \times 1$. Call $A$ the lower left vertex of the front face of $C$, and let $B$ the vertex opposite $A$ in $C$ (that is, $B$ is the upper right vertex of the posterior face of $C$). How many different "paths" lead from the point $A$ to point $B$ along the hub wires, if the only directions possible are: backwards, to the right and up?

Comment: Since the starting point is at the front of the cube, in this context, backwards means toward the back of the cube rather than retracing your steps.  The use of the term backwards is needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by breaking down the word problem into more mathematical language, using coordinates to simplify the geometry. For example, we can let $A=(0,0,0)$, and $B=(5,5,5)$. The question also gives us three directions: right is $a=(1,0,0)$, up is $b=(0,1,0)$, and backwards is $c=(0,0,1)$. Admittedly, "backwards" is a bit ambiguous, but once you formalize the words into numbers, it's hard to imagine any other sensible interpretation.

To reach $B$ from $A$, we need to go right five times, up five times, and backwards five times. Any order of these moves (that is, $5a+5b+5c$) will reach $B$, so you just need to count how many words there are if you only use the letters $\{a,b,c\}$, and you use each one exactly five times.

Comment: I think interpreting the word problem is the main concern here, so I purposely omitted the counting solution. If this is for homework, you should try it on your own. I'll include the counting solution if it's requested.

Comment: @YAHIRJOSUE Your solution of $756756$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks, no, it's not homework, it's a doubt about an exercise.
Attached to the counting solution, is it correct, right?
Let us consider that the movements occur under the words Up (U), Right (R) and Back (B), so the question is how many 15-letter words with 5 letters U, R and B can be formed?
Therefore there will be ${n \choose U,R,B}= \frac{15!}{5!\cdot5!\cdot5!} =756,756$ paths.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reach from $A$ $(0,0,0)$ to $B$ $(5,5,5)$ in $C$ you must go

- $5$ steps up ($U$)
- $5$ steps right ($R$)
- $5$ steps back ($B$),

in some arbitrary order, a total of $15$ steps.

This is exactly same as number of distinct permutations of the string $UUUUURRRRRBBBBB$, which is $\frac{15}{5!5!5!}$

Comment: Thanks, greetings from Mexico!